# Azure Resource Manager Virtual Machines LUN limit of 4?

Tags: powershell, azure

Add-AzureVMDataDisk (for classic VMs) allowed me to specify a LUN from 0-15. Now Add-AzureRmVMDataDisk (for ARM VMs) has a limit of 0-3.

1. Why the change?
2. How can I add more that 4 disks to my ARM VM?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the number of data disks you can add to an ARM VM is dependent on its family and size, so a A2 VM can have 4 data disks but an A3 VM can have up to 8 data disks. at the top end some of the D and G family VMs can have up to 32 data disks. if you use the ARM portal http://Portal.Azure.com to create a virtual machine you can see all the details of the VM including the number of Processors, the amount of RAM and the number of data disks you can have.